# Recursively edit files based on parent directory's name

Tags: linux, regular-expression, rename

I have a large directory with hundreds of folders, all following the naming scheme "a_b_x", with x being a random word. In every one of these folders there are 3 text files, all with a couple of strings containing "a_b_x" as well.

I'm trying to rename all of the directories and change the strings inside the files from "a_b_x" to "a_x", meaning the "b_" is supposed to be removed. I hope to accomplish this with some sed wizardry, as manually editing all of the files would take several hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this command :

```
for folder in $(ls); do
    for file in $(ls $folder); do
        sed -i 's/_b//' $folder/$file
    done
    mv $folder ${folder/_b/}
done
```

- First loop is browsing directories.
- Second loop is editing contents of files located in folders.

  After leaving second loop, first one is renaming folders.

Another way for dealing with spaces in filenames which would be interpreted as IFS :

```
ls | while read folder ; do
 ls "$folder" | while read file; do
  sed -i 's/_b//' "$folder/$file"
 done
 mv "$folder" "${folder/_b/}"
done
```

Comment: [Never use for loops with ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), use while and quote the variables to deal with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should always [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Try this (thanks to [stephane-chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/) for suggesting `./*/`):

```
for folder in ./*/; do     
      sed -i 's/_b//g' "$f"/*; mv "$folder" "${folder/_b/}"; 
 done
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `find` has the same issues as parsing the output of `ls`. Use `-exec` with find, or just loop over `*/`: `for folder in ./*/`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas find does not have these problems when used in combination with `IFS=` and `-print0` (which I forgot in my original answer.

Comment: For `-print0`, you need `read -d ''` for which you need `zsh` or `bash`. Note the `for folder in ./*/` which I mentioned earlier  would include symlinks to directories (whether it's desirable or not)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ah, yes, I am a `bash` person, true. Why do you need `-d` for `bash`? It seems to work fine as is.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
root@testbox:~# mkdir test
root@testbox:~# cd test
root@testbox:~/test# mkdir -p a_b_x{1..10} # populate directories
root@testbox:~/test# printf 'a_b_x\na_b_y\nfoo\nbar\n' | \
    tee a_b_x{1..10}/somefile # populate files
a_b_x
a_b_y
foo
bar
```

Rename directories:

```
root@testbox:~/test# find . -name a_b_\* -type d -print0 | \
    xargs -r0 rename -v 's/a_b_/a_/'
./a_b_x10 renamed as ./a_x10
./a_b_x5 renamed as ./a_x5
./a_b_x7 renamed as ./a_x7
./a_b_x4 renamed as ./a_x4
./a_b_x8 renamed as ./a_x8
./a_b_x3 renamed as ./a_x3
./a_b_x9 renamed as ./a_x9
./a_b_x6 renamed as ./a_x6
./a_b_x1 renamed as ./a_x1
./a_b_x2 renamed as ./a_x2
```

Edit files:

```
root@testbox:~/test# find . ! -name \*.bak -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 sed -i.bak 's,a_b_,a_,'
root@testbox:~/test# cat a_x4/somefile
a_x
a_y
foo
bar
```

Remove backups if all ok:

```
root@vm8583:~/test# find . -name \*.bak -type f -delete
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for rename, in Perl no less! Is it part of the default Perl installation?

Comment: This `rename` (`prename`) is from default perl installaton on Debian, the same can be achieved with `rename` (`rename.ul`) from util-linux package with slightly different call syntax: `rename.ul -v a_b_ a_ ...`.